# Adjoint of free functor from FinSet to category of finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Let FinSet be the category of finite sets with mathematical functions. Let FinVec be the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces. Then there is the free functor FinSet $\to$ FinVec that maps the set $S$ to the vector space of linear combinations of elements of $S$.

Does this functor have a left adjoint? If so, what is it?

Comment: A left adjoint or a right adjoint?

Comment: @Con, left adjoint yes.

Comment: @EricWofsey, left adjoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As people are asking in comments, we need to know whether you want the free functor $F : \mathsf{FinSet} \to \mathsf{FinVec}$ to have a *left* or a *right* adjoint. The answer is a bit subtle and depends on your underlying field.

---

First, why might it not have a right adjoint? Any functor that calls itself "free" should be left adjoint to a forgetful functor... The issue is that the forgetful functor $U$ on $\text{FinVect}$ takes values in *infinite* sets if your field $k$ is infinite.

- If $k$ is finite, then the underlying set functor $U$ will work, with $F \dashv U$ as usual (do you see why?).
- If $k$ is infinite, then $F$ is the restriction of the free functor on the whole of $\mathsf{Set}$ to the (full) subcategory $\mathsf{FinSet}$. Then if $F$ *did* have a right adjoint, $U'$, we would have (if $\iota : \mathsf{FinSet} \hookrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ is the inclusion):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(\iota X, \iota U' V) 
&\cong \text{Hom}_\mathsf{FinSet}(X, U' V) \\
&\cong \text{Hom}_\mathsf{FinVect}(FX, V) \\
&\cong \text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(\iota X, UV)
\end{aligned}
$$

So $\iota U'$ would have to be $U$ (the usual forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$). Notice in the case of $k$ finite this is OK, since the underlying set of a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field *does* factor through $\mathsf{FinSet}$. However if $k$ is infinite, then $UV$ is not of the form $\iota Z$ for any finite set $Z$, so $U'$ cannot exist.

---

Second, why won't $F$ have a left adjoint?

This is much less subtle. If $F$ has a left adjoint, then it preserves limits. In particular, it should preserve the terminal object. But $F1 = k^1$ is *not* terminal in $\mathsf{FinVect}$ (do you see why?).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I'll just add that $\text{Hom}_\mathsf{FinVect}(FX, V) \cong \text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(\iota X, UV)$ makes $F$ and $U$ $\iota$-[relative adjoints](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+adjoint+functor).